# Match on Set.empty behaves differently to "".split(",").toSet (PartialFunction)

Tags: scala

Why does `Set.empty` behave different to `"".split(",").toSet` in a `PartialFunction`?

```
val x = Set.empty
val y = Set("foo")
val z = "".split(",").toSet

val fooBar: PartialFunction[String, Int] = {
  case "foo" => 5
  case "bar" => 6
}

y.map(fooBar) // works
x.map(fooBar) // works
z.map(fooBar) // scala.MatchError:  (of class java.lang.String)
```

Comment: `"".split(",").toSet` returns a singleton set containing the empty string, not an empty set. The match in `fooBar` therefore fails.

Comment: It works on `x`, because `x` has no elements to map. It works on `y`, because the function is defined on `"foo"`. The problem is that (as @Lee said) `z` is not empty and you try to apply `fooBar` on `""`, which causes the matcherror, since your function is not defined on `""`.

Comment: Great, thanks for that answer. IntelliJ's worksheet tells me that `"".split(",").toSet` is of type `scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set()`...

Comment: @Lee If you want that reputation than you should answer. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two aren't the same:

```
scala> val x = Set.empty
x: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Nothing] = Set()

scala> x.size
res0: Int = 0

scala> val z = "".split(",").toSet
z: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set("")

scala> z.size
res1: Int = 1
```

The `split` line produces a set consisting of one element, which is the empty string. You see just `Set()` in the output but actually within the `()` is the empty string. :)